# converting angularfirelist to array

Tags: ionic-framework, angularfire2

I would like to ask how to subscribe an angularfirelist to an array of objects.
This way doesn't work, here is a preview of my code

```
 Moniteurs: MoniteurModel[]; 

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public db:AngularFireDatabase, 
    public http: HttpClient) {
        this.db.list<MoniteurModel[]>('/Pannes').valueChanges().subscribe((data)=>{
        this.Moniteurs.push(data);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to say there are a few things that can be addressed, but my primarily you are pushing an array from your `valuesChanges()` subscription into an array. I doubt you wanted that and would rather update the `Moniteurs` array with the new values from Firebase:

```
  Moniteurs: MoniteurModel[]; 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
     public navParams: NavParams,
     public db:AngularFireDatabase, 
     public http: HttpClient) {

    this.db.list<MoniteurModel>('/Pannes').valueChanges().subscribe((values) => {
      // If you want to push in values, however this may lead to duplicates
      values.forEach((value) => this.Moniteurs.push(value));

      // If you want Moniteurs to be just the new data
      this.Moniteurs = values;
    });
  }
```